# Binary Conversion - using (An x 2)^n...(A0 x 2)^0

Tags: binary, decimal, data-conversion

What am I missing here? I'm rather new to handwritten binary to decimal conversion, and I can't figure out why, for me at least, 1110 and 1111 appear to both equal 15, but I know that 1110 = 14.

```
Binary = 1110
n =      3210
calc = (1*2)^3 = 8
       (1*2)^2 = 4
       (1*2)^1 = 2
       (0*2)^0 = 1
       = 15

Binary = 1111
n =      3210
calc = (1*2)^3 = 8
       (1*2)^2 = 4
       (1*2)^1 = 2
       (1*2)^0 = 1
       = 15
```

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth now that I know what I'm doing, it is 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your confusion lies in your formula being incorrect, it is not `(An*2)^n` it is `An*(2^n)` ([`PEMDAS`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations#Mnemonics)):

```
1110
1 * 2^3 = 8
1 * 2^2 = 4
1 * 2^1 = 2
0 * 2^0 = 0
         --- 
          14

1111
1 * 2^3 = 8
1 * 2^2 = 4
1 * 2^1 = 2
1 * 2^0 = 1 
         ---
          15
```

Comment: Well that makes much more sense. The SQL Bible actually writes it as (An*2)^n...(An-1*2)^n, etc. Must be a misprint.

Answer (score 1):

Your formula (in your question title) just has the wrong precedence. It's not `(An x 2)^n…(A0 x 2)^0`, but rather `An x (2^n)…A0 x (2^0)`.

```
Binary = 1110
n =      3210
calc = 1*2^3 = 1*8 = 8
       1*2^2 = 1*4 = 4
       1*2^1 = 1*2 = 2
       0*2^0 = 0*1 = 0
       = 14

Binary = 1111
n =      3210
calc = 1*2^3 = 1*8 = 8
       1*2^2 = 1*4 = 4
       1*2^1 = 1*2 = 2
       1*2^0 = 1*1 = 1
       = 15
```

Comment: Well that makes much more sense. The SQL Bible actually writes it as (An*2)^n...(An-1*2)^n, etc. Must be a misprint.

Comment: Maybe you can get them to adopt the Knuth book bug bounty system: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth_reward_check :-)